# What is the correct way to load prebuilt SQlite databases with or without PouchDB in a React App

Tags: reactjs, sqlite, pouchdb, preload

Currently I'm writing a React App and struggling with a simple reading from a SQlite database.

**Edit because of unclear question**:

***The goal is to read from the database without any backend, because it needs to read from the database even when it is offline.

***I'm aiming for a ONE TIME file conversion, then just pouchdb queries offline. But I don't want to do it manually because there are around 6k+ registries.

***Or SQL queries from the browser without any APIs, but I need to support Internet Explorer, so WebSQL is not an option. I've tried sqlite3 library, but I can't make it work with Create React App.

The solution I tried was to use PouchDB for reading the file, but I'm coming to a conclusion that it is NOT possible to **PRELOAD** a SQlite file with PouchDB without using cordova (I'm not comfortable with it, I don't want any servers running), or even with some kind of adapter.

So is this the right way of doing things?

Is there any way that I would not loose my .db data, and have to convert it all of it manually?

Should I forget about supporting this features on IE?

Thanks :)

Comment: How bad would it be to forget about SQL? SQL *and* offline first together make for quite awkward bedfellows. Meanwhile CouchDB / PouchDB makes offline first nearly effortless.

Comment: Martin Bramwell, is there a way to convert a .db file to pouch/couch? It's not ideal to do it manually.

Comment: is this to be a one time conversion or continuous?

Comment: It is supposed to be a one time conversion.

Comment: Giovanni Klein Camoigoto, just wondering if you have fully working code in react? I am trying to connect existing sqlite db on ubuntu with browser and reactJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sqlite3 example "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS some_table;";
sqlite3 example "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS some_table (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, anattr VARCHAR, anotherattr VARCHAR);";
sqlite3 example "INSERT INTO some_table VALUES (NULL, '1stAttr', 'AttrA');";
sqlite3 example "INSERT INTO some_table VALUES (NULL, '2ndAttr', 'AttrB');";

## Create three JSON fragment files
sqlite3 example ".output result_prefix.json" "SELECT '{ \"docs\": ['";
sqlite3 example ".output rslt.json" "SELECT '{ \"_id\": \"someTable_' || SUBSTR(\"000000000\" || id, LENGTH(\"000000000\" || id) - 8, 9) || '\", \"anattr\": \"' || anattr || '\", \"anotherattr\": \"' || anotherattr || '\" },' FROM some_table;";
sqlite3 example ".output result_suffix.json" "SELECT '] }'";

## strip trailing comma of last record
sed -i '$ s/.$//' rslt.json;

## concatenate to a single file
cat result_prefix.json rslt.json result_suffix.json > result.json;

cat result.json;
```

You should be able simply to paste the above lines onto the (unix) command line, seeing output:

```
{ "docs": [
{ "_id": "someTable_000000001", "anattr": "1stAttr", "anotherattr": "AttrA" },
{ "_id": "someTable_000000002", "anattr": "2ndAttr", "anotherattr": "AttrB" }
] }
```

If you have `jq` installed you can do instead ...

```
cat result.json | jq .
```

... obtaining:

```
{
  "docs": [
    {
      "_id": "someTable_000000001",
      "anattr": "1stAttr",
      "anotherattr": "AttrA"
    },
    {
      "_id": "someTable_000000002",
      "anattr": "2ndAttr",
      "anotherattr": "AttrB"
    }
  ]
}
```

You'll find an example of how quickly to initialize PouchDB from JSON files in part 2 of the blog post [Prebuilt databases with PouchDB](https://pouchdb.com/2016/04/28/prebuilt-databases-with-pouchdb.html).

So, if you have a CouchDB server available you can do the following;

```
export COUCH_DB=example;
export COUCH_URL= *** specify yours here ***;
export FILE=result.json;

## Drop database
curl -X DELETE ${COUCH_URL}/${COUCH_DB};

## Create database
curl -X PUT ${COUCH_URL}/${COUCH_DB};

## Load database from JSON file
curl -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST "${COUCH_URL}/${COUCH_DB}/_bulk_docs"  -d @${FILE};

## Extract database with meta data to PouchDB initialization file
pouchdb-dump ${COUCH_URL}/${COUCH_DB} > example.json

## Inspect PouchDB initialization file
cat example.json | jq .
```

Obviously you'll need some adaptations, but the above should give you no problems.

Comment: So, that helped? :-)

Comment: Yeah totally, just converted the entire base :)

Comment: A tangential point, for future readers having a much more complicated database ... converting a SQLite database to MySql is fairly easy.  With that done you can take advantage of some very powerful tools for generating JSON output. See [JSON functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-function-reference.html) and [JSON data types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html)  Bear in mind there's quite a steep learning curve for those, though.

Answer (score 0):

Since Couch/Pouch-DB are document-oriented DBs all records aka docs there are just JSON aka JS-objects. In my RN app when I met similar task I just put all docs I wanted to be "prepopulated" in PouchDB in an array of JS-objects, import it as module in my app and then write them during app init to PDB as necessarry docs. That's all prepopulation. How to export your SQL DB records to JSON - you decide, surely it depends on source DB structure and data logic you want to be in PDB.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's not answering my question, my question was the correct way of loading SQLite files using adapters in a web environment. The tables doesen't have any sort of relation between them, they are just plain tables without any blobs and so on, but I need an automated way to convert it, because there are 6000 registries on those.

Comment: "but I need an automated way to convert it" - first question then: convert to what? And how this "what" is intended to be used afterwards in your app? You tagged question "pouchdb" so my first guess was that you need local PDB instance with some necessary data finally. If not - probably you selected wrong tag/topic. What do you want to get at the end of the day? SQL DB in browser? Not clear now.

Comment: What I am seeing here is a inadequately formulated question.  We should not have to keep asking for further details, nor should we have to guess at what you are trying to achieve.  Please update your question to explain how the relevant parts of your system will behave when you finally get it doing what you want.  What will happen on initial start?  on a user first connection?  on a user subsequent connection?

Comment: I just need to read the data at some given time, it doesn't matter if it is on the login or not. I need a one time conversion from Sqlite to PouchDb, or some other way of querying Sqlite in the browser offline.

Comment: I am asking if you know what is the recommended way of doing it, or even if it exists.